# What are some good resources for learning Motion 4?

Tags: motion, learning-resources

I am trying to learn Apple's Motion 4, which is pretty complex. I'm looking for some free online tutorials to learn the ins and outs of Motion. Where can I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [rippletraining](http://www.rippletraining.com) to be very helpful. [Larry Jordan](http://www.larryjordan.biz) is also a good starting point.

[Alex4D](http://alex4d.wordpress.com) puts out some really cool, easy to learn from, Motion templates. [Sight-Creations](http://www.youtube.com/user/fxmah) is another great resource to find Motion templates.

You're also going to find lots of good starting material on YouTube.

- [TimesaverTutorials](http://www.youtube.com/user/timesavertutorials/videos)
- [DoApproductionss](http://www.youtube.com/user/doaproductionss/videos)
- [Dan Allen](http://www.youtube.com/user/danonabouncycastle/videos)

If you didn't know, you can also save YouTube search queries and subscribe to them in [Google Reader](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference). I find a lot of good stuff there too.

Lastly, I want to mention [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com). The quality of videos you're going to find there is really astonishing. Check out the group [Motion tips & tricks](https://vimeo.com/groups/98259/videos/41074603)

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: Thanks! Great resources! I've learned a *lot* already!!!!